# MVC5 AngularJS data is not passing from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing one application in AngularJS with MVC5. I am trying to get Data based on ID from database. My server side code is working correctly.
I am finding difficulties in binding data to controls in angularJS controller. I am new to the world of AngularJS. 
This is what I am trying so far.

```
<tr ng-repeat="usr in userList">
            <td>
                {{usr.ID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{usr.FNAME}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{usr.LNAME}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{usr.USERNAME}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{usr.JOINING_DATE}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Edit User" span ng-click="editUser(usr)"/>
                <span ng-click="editUser(usr)" class="btnRed">Delete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This is my service.js code.

```
 this.getUser = function (ID) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "CreateUser/getUserByNo",
            params: {
                id: JSON.stringify(ID)
            }
        });
        return response;
    }
```

This is my angularJS controller code.

```
 $scope.editUser = function (usr) {
        debugger;
        var getData = CreateUserService.getUser(usr.ID);
        getData.then(function (emp) {
            $scope.usr = emp.data;
            $scope.FNAME = usr.FNAME;
            $scope.Lname = usr.Lname;
            $scope.UserName = usr.UserName;
            $scope.JoiningDate = usr.JoiningDate;
        },
        function () {
            alert('Error in getting records');
        });
    }
```

I am trying to bind data to the below textboxes.

```
 <input type="text" id="Fname" class="Fname" ng-model="Fname" />
```

In angularJS controller my data is not binding using below code.
 $scope.FNAME = usr.FNAME; May I get some idea where I am doing things wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng-model="Fname"` to `ng-model="FNAME"`.

Probably, this will do the binding.

Comment: I wrote   $scope.Fname = usr.FNAME and This is worked. Thanks for the trick.

Comment: All the best @NiranjanGodbole